# Android Telegram Project Runtime Error

Tags: android, runtime, telegram

I have downloaded the Telegram project from the following repository (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) and I have edited the *BuildVars.java* to put my **APP_ID** and **APP_HASH**, and also I have registered in hockeyapp.net to have get the **HOCKEY_APP_HASH**. And now, when I run the project it stops having an Exception. As I see, it says that "***org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader***" is not found. But it is there in "java/org/telegram/messenger/" folder. Please help me to figure out this problem.

---

Log cat output:

```
02-07 20:26:36.204: D/AndroidRuntime(1089): Shutting down VM
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): Process: org.telegram.messenger, PID: 1089
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.telegram.messenger-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:517)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4370)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:143)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.telegram.messenger-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:976)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:512)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     ... 10 more
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         ... 13 more
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lorg/telegram/messenger/ApplicationLoader;" not found
02-07 20:26:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1089):         ... 17 more
02-07 20:26:43.890: I/Process(1089): Sending signal. PID: 1089 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign some 32 length string to **HOCKEY_APP_HASH** in `BuildVars.java`. I used all zeros and it works fine for now. I will try to update how to bypass using Hockey and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Manifest file, try to replace `".ApplicationLoader"` with `"org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader"` and try to rebuild project. Maybe this helps You.